# Problemas al intentar guardar datos en base de datos

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy pasando datos de una tabla a otro, las misma tienen diferente colecion de datos. En la tabla origen los atributos se guardan sin tildes y signos, en su lugar estan los siguientes textos

&iacute

Mi problema es que quiero guardarlos en la otra tabla con sus respectivos acentos pero no logro hacerlo. Se guardan con el texto &iacute . Mi problema es solo al guardar, yo puedo mostrarlo en la web con sua centos sin problema.

La tabla orgen esta en utf8_general_ci y mi tabla origen tiene la siguiente coleccion utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci

No se que hacer para poder guardar los datos como lo requiero.

Utiice utf8_encode, pero la doc me dice que no tiene relacion con lo que necesito. Existe alguna forma de hacer esto?

De la siguiente forma guardo los datos en mi tabla con laravel php

```
$id=vwdh0_k2_items::where('id',42327)->where('plugins','y')
            ->select('fulltext')->get();
        foreach($id as $data){
            objeto::create([
                'categoria_id'=>$data->fulltext,
            ]);
        }
```

intente guardar con mb_convert_encoding, o utf sin exito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con la función [html_entity_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.html-entity-decode.php) que tal como dice su documentación:

> Convierte todas las entidades HTML a sus caracteres correspondientes

pues **esos textos** como tu denominas, son en realidad denominados [entidades HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Entity).

También podrias revisar en tu código si en alguna parte estás usando la función [htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.htmlentities.php) que hace justamente lo contrario:

> Convierte todos los caracteres aplicables a entidades HTML

y quitarla para que no lo haga más.

Comment: oño la madre mano, gracias. Me estaba volviendo loco ya.

Comment: jeje, no eres el primero :-)  De todos modos ojo con eso, pues si estas trabajando con una base de datos ya creada con muchos registros de ese tipo ya almacenados deberias hacerte un script que recorriera toda la tabla e hiciera esa conversión para tenerlos todos a la vez corregidos (haz siempre una copia de seguridad de las tablas afectadas por si acaso y para no tener una tabla con algunos si y otros no en la misma columna)

Comment: Eso de usar las entidades HTML en lugar del texto con su collation adecuada se usaba más antiguamente por programadores sin demasiada experiencia que de este modo se aseguraban que no hubiera corrupción de datos al guardarlos desde páginas con collations distintas y no entendian el porque (lo digo porque yo he pasado por ahi! he sido uno de ellos! jeje)

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias, si estoy haciendo efectivamente eso. Feliz dia y respuesta marcada como correcta.

Comment: Perfecto! Gracias por colaborar con el buen funcionamiento del sitio :-)  Saludos!